# Group data by a column and check if the contents of the designated columns are identical across the groups

Tags: r, group-by, duplicates, grouping, distinct

I have a datatable as following:

```
example_data <- data.table(
  group_number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  B = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24),
  other_columns = c(-0.03821019, -1.65126924, 0.26851449, -0.95818859,
                    0.51500988, 1.01449388, -0.65350743, -0.26931109,
                    1.04377564, 0.36648139, 2.47164652, -0.49508173,
                    0.53431890, -0.35798755, 0.38692761, 0.62482005)
)
```

Here, I want to first group rows by group_number. And then if the rows of columns A and B of one group are identical to the rows of columns A and B of another group, then I would like to remove the duplicated group and leave only one group.

For example, in the above table, since rows of columns A and B from group_number==1 are identical to the rows of columns A and B from group_number==2, I would like to remove all the rows that belongs to group_number 2 (rows 5:8).

The desried output should look as follows:

```
example_data <- data.table(
  group_number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  B = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24),
  other_columns = c(-0.03821019, -1.65126924, 0.26851449, -0.95818859,
                    1.04377564, 0.36648139, 2.47164652, -0.49508173,
                    0.53431890, -0.35798755, 0.38692761, 0.62482005)
)
```

The job can be done using `distinct(example_data,A,B,.keep_all = TRUE)`, but this is not the answer I am seeking for. Distinct function groups data by a combination of columns A and B and then see if there are duplicated values across that group. I want to group by group_number and check if the contents of columns A and B are identical across the group_number.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: FYI, the `data.table`-alernative to `distinct(example_data, A, B, .keep_all = TRUE)` is `unique(example_data, by = c("A", "B"))` *I think*. Please explain why your approach is not the answer you are after. Do you want a check (e.g. flag) or a deletion?

Comment: Hello @Friede, thank you for your comment! I am seeking the approach that groups by "group_number" and then removes duplicated rows (in a chunk) based on the group level rather than grouping by columns A and B. I need a different approach because the data I have is far more complicated than the example_data I posted. Please let me know if my anser was unclear.

Comment: How do we know which rows should be deleted? Those with higher `group_number`?

Comment: @Friede, yes I want to remove the groups with higher group_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can try the following. `split` the data.table into a list based on `group_number`. Then, you can extract the rows that are not duplicated based on columns `A` and `B`. Note in the `lapply` we use `[` to extract rows, and have an empty argument to indicate all rows should be included (and selecting `A` and `B` columns).

```
lst <- split(example_data, example_data$group_number)
do.call(rbind, lst[!duplicated(lapply(lst, `[`, , c("A", "B")))])
```

**Output**

```
    group_number A  B other_columns
 1:            1 1  5   -0.03821019
 2:            1 2  6   -1.65126924
 3:            1 3  7    0.26851449
 4:            1 4  8   -0.95818859
 5:            3 1 13    1.04377564
 6:            3 2 14    0.36648139
 7:            3 3 15    2.47164652
 8:            3 4 16   -0.49508173
 9:            4 1 21    0.53431890
10:            4 2 22   -0.35798755
11:            4 3 23    0.38692761
12:            4 4 24    0.62482005
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Making the table into a list is a brilliant idea! And yes, this is the approach I was seeking for. It works nicely with my original data as well. I do get a warning sign next to the code saying "missing argument to function call", but the code runs regardless.